# How to remove repetition from this Ruby function?

Tags: ruby

Can someone tell me how to simplify this Ruby function?

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.users_sort_column      = "created_at"      
    self.companies_sort_column  = "name"
    self.people_sort_column     = "last_name"
    self.projects_sort_column   = "name"
    self.invoices_sort_column   = "number"
    self.payments_sort_column   = "number"

    self.users_sort_direction     = "desc"      
    self.companies_sort_direction = "asc"
    self.people_sort_direction    = "asc"
    self.projects_sort_direction  = "asc"
    self.invoices_sort_direction  = "desc"
    self.payments_sort_direction  = "desc"
  end

end
```

There's too much repetition in it. Thanks for any help.

**P.S: Each `user` should be able to update his profile, that's why I am storing all those values in the database rather than in the models.**

Comment: You can use `send("#{object type}_sort_#{column or direction}")`, but I suspect all the common names is a sign you should dry up other parts of your code.

Comment: Considering how much variation you have in there, where even the attribute names are in two different groups, the best you can hope for is to collapse this into a Hash instead of doing direct method calls, but the benefits of that are dubious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no repetition code can be written as follows:

```
def set_defaults
  sort_column_direction = {
    users:      ["created_at",  "desc"],
    companies:  ["name",       "asc"],
    people:     ["last_name",  "asc"],
    projects:   ["name",        "asc"],
    invoices:   ["number",      "desc"],
    payments:   ["number",      "desc"]
  }
  sort_column_direction.each do |key,value|
    self.send("#{key}_sort_column=", value[0])
    self.send("#{key}_sort_direction=", value[1])
  end 
end
```

Comment: Ah that's it. Thanks. Except that I had to add an `=` just after `#{key}_sort_column`. I will try to edit that in your code.

Comment: Oh just realised you added that already by yourself. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to have an hash pointing from a name to an array of sort column and direction. For instance:

```
sorts["user"] = ["created_at", "desc"]
sorts["companies"] = ["name", "asc"]
... etc ....
```

Also you can use symbols instead of strings for the keys. The code will become a bit shorter but more importantly both parameters of a given sort are at one place making the code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using something very similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to your current organizational format:

```
def set_defaults
  self.sort = {
    users:     {column: "created_at", direction: "desc"},
    companies: {column: "name",       direction: "asc"},
    people:    {column: "last_name",  direction: "asc"},
    projects:  {column: "name",       direction: "asc"},
    invoices:  {column: "number",     direction: "desc"},
    payments:  {column: "number",     direction: "desc"}
  }
end
```

Elsewhere:

```
module DefaultSort
  def default_sort
    column    = Default.sort[self.name.tableize.to_sym][:column]
    direction = Default.sort[self.name.tableize.to_sym][:direction]
    self.order("#{column} #{direction}")
  end
end

class User
  extend DefaultSort
end

User.default_sort.to_sql #=> "SELECT * FROM users ORDER created_at desc"
```

Comment: are you sure this is valid ruby?

Comment: are you sure? Does not seem like a ruby hash def to me

Comment: This is the new hash style: http://lassebunk.dk/2013/03/11/sublime-text-convert-ruby-1-8-to-1-9-style-hash-syntax/

Comment: ohh... I am old now it seems :(. Maybe it is worth it that you indicate this will not work in ruby 1.8 then?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sounds good except that in my case each `user` should be able to update all those columns individually. Therefore, I'm afraid I need to store all those values in the database. I wonder how this can be done using the Hash you kindly provided.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree there's too much repetition here.  Though it's not inspiring Ruby code, it's clear what you're doing.

You can certainly set up some kind of data structure, eg hash, and then set these values via metaprogramming by looping through the data structure.  But the code will look more convoluted, and the number of lines will increase.  So doing it this way is not an improvement.  Remember: clarity is king.

If you're doing object oriented programming (which I suspect you're doing), then you would have classes: User, Company, People, Project, etc.  How about set the sort_column
and sort_direction in each of the classes?  Attributes like these should be inside the class for better information-hiding.

If you're using Rails, the convention is to define a default scope in each model, such as

```
default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

Comment: OK, but what if a `user` wants to override that value?

Comment: You can create other scopes in the model.  You can also create lambda scopes by passing in arguments to the scopes so it's completely flexible.

Comment: OK, that definitely makes sense. But in my app I need to store the sort columns and directions for each user.

Comment: The defaults can still be on the model, and you let the user set their preference to override.